# “overriding” private methods with upcasting call in java

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

```
public class PrivateOverride {
    private void f() {
        System.out.println("PrivateOverride f()");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrivateOverride po = new DerivedWithOutD();
        po.d();// PrivateOverride f()

        PrivateOverride poD = new DerivedWithD();
        poD.d();//Derived f()
    }

    public void d() {
        f();
    }
}

class DerivedWithOutD extends PrivateOverride {
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("Derived f()");
    }
}
class DerivedWithD extends PrivateOverride {
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("Derived f()");
    }

    public void d() {
        f();
    }
}
```

As the codes above show, when DerivedWithOutD don't override the method d(), it calls the f() belong to PrivateOverride, is that because method f() of PrivateOverride can't be overrided?But the d() inherit from PrivateOverride should belong to DerivedWithOutD, why d() calls the private f()?  And why DerivedWithD class seems do the override, And can call the public f()? Also ,when I change the f() of PrivateOverride to public , it all print Derived f(), It confuse me now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A private method can't be overridden by sub-classes. If the sub-classes declare a method with the same signature as a private method in the parent class, the sub-class method doesn't override the super-class method.

When you call method `d()`, if `d()` is not overridden by the sub-class, the executed method is `PrivateOverride`'s `d()`. When that method calls `f()`, it sees the private `f()` method defined in `PrivateOverride`. Since that method is not overridden (as it can't be), it calls that method and not the `f()` method of the sub-class.

If `d()` is overridden, the `d()` method of the sub-class `DerivedWithD` is executed. When that method calls `f()`, it calls the `f()` method of `DerivedWithD`.

If `f()` is no longer private, the `f()` method in the sub-classes now overrides the `f()` method of the super-class, and therefore `f()` of the sub-class is executed in both cases.

Comment: like you said if d() is not overridden by the sub-class, the executed method is PrivateOverride's d() ,  then why when f() is public  the method d() calls DerivedWithD's f() ?  the executed method is not PrivateOverride's d() when f() is public?

Comment: @Jack If `f()` is public, the sub-classes override `f()`. Therefore, even if you call the base class `d()`, it calls the sub-class version of `f()`. That's how polymorphism works.

Comment: Thanks Eran , I seem to understand now , you mean that all method will belong to the base class if the sub-class didn't override it?  Even I use DerivedWithOutD d = new DerivedWithOutD(); d calls the method always belong to base class if it did not override it

Comment: @Jack If you call a method of the base class, and the sub-class didn't override it, the base class method will be executed. Not sure what you mean by "all method will belong to the base class".

Comment: I thought the method  inherit from the base class  will belong to the sub-calss even it did'nt override the method, however, throught this demo above, the inherited mothod still belong to the base class , this is why DerivedWithOutD d = new DerivedWithOutD(); d.d() still print PrivateOverride f() ,right?